# Windows 8 clicking on favourites opens whole structure

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, favorites

Hello my windows 8 explorer started to act really weird. When I click on any favorite folder shortcut on the left sidebar of my explorer windows (wheres the directory structure located) for example on 'www', then it scolls all the way down and opens whole path to the folder like C:\folder1\folder2\folder...\www. This behaviour really annoys me. For example in case of miss click it is not as easy as just move pointer one item lower I have to scroll all the way up and try again.

How can I change this behavior? What went wrong? When I click on favorite folder I just want to open it as it is. :(

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Solved by reinstaling. Not elegant though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happend again and I accidentaly found solution. Under `view` in explorer's toolbar click `navigation pane` (first icon) and (un)check `Expand to open folder` option.

This functionality is similar to `eclipse`'s `link with editor` for those who know it.